# Yii2 ActiveRecord getting new relation after eager loading

Tags: yii2

I have a project in Yii2 where I have two models in a one-to-one relation.

The two models are `Plan` and `Subscription`, and each has a `getSubscription` and `getPlan` method respectively.

I am eager loading a large group of them by using with:

```
$plans = Plan::find()->with('subscription')->all();
```

However, I am modifying some of the  `Plan`s `subscription_id` with:

```
$plan->subscription_id = 5;
$plan->save();
```

The problem is that now `$plan->subscription` contains the original `Subscription`, and not the `Subscription` with the new id.

Is there a way to make Yii2 grab the new `Subscription`, only after the id has been updated (and not lazy load all of the `Subscription`s)?

Comment: how do you modify it? share that code as well

Comment: @AzraarAzward simply with $plan->subscription_id = 5; and then $plan->save(); I'll update my question.

Comment: Which version of Yii you're using. How these relationships are defined?

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstand, you can do as this

```
<?php

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Plan extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->on(self::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE, [$this, 'afterUpdateHandler']);
    }

    /**
     * @param \yii\db\AfterSaveEvent $event
     */
    public function afterUpdateHandler($event)
    {
        if (isset($event->changedAttributes['subscription_id']))
        {
            $this->subscription = NULL;
        }
    }

    // ...
}

?>
```

**Next time** you call `$plan->subscription`, the `subscription` your `Plan` associated with will be retrofitted.

> Instead of implementing it as an event handler, you could also rewrite the `afterSave` method.